# Magento 1: Editing Category Name from admin

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I am editing a category name from Magento 1 admin. The changes and shows in the breadcrumbs but it does not show up in the navigation menu bar. Does it mean that they are manually/statically written in some menu file or is it some other issue?

The other day when we as well tried to deactivate a category, it does not go away from the nav menu but on click, the page says 404 error.

Comment: yes may you used to manually or comes from admin menus and you given title static.

Comment: no. when i edit from the admin the name it does not change in the front end menu....like if i edit Menu 1 as Menu A - it changes in the admin but does not change in the front end

Comment: is your store is on live mode?

Comment: please share your store url

Comment: kindly see this n advise - https://ibb.co/jrpnPh8

Comment: ok can you share store details please

Comment: i can't share that for confidentiality concerns. if u can suggest; what could be the probable reasons. is the menu static? if yes, where or how to look for that file where i can change it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103127/discussion-between-sarvesh-dineshkumar-patel-and-inspired-by-normal).

Comment: There could be a number of reasons for this 1 being that whoever wrote your template could have hardcoded them within a .phtml file another is they have included the menu within a CMS static block and finally you could have an extension which manages you menu which you may need to modify to get the result you are trying to acheive